# apache2 rewrite is working, but doesn´t keep URL

Tags: rewrite, apache2, httpd

I was looking around google for some days now and can´t get it to work.
With apache rewrite: domain.com > test.com/test (but keep the URL domain.com in browser)

The whole SSL Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName xxx
        ServerAlias domain.com test.com

        DocumentRoot /srv/www/test/htdocs

        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog "/srv/www/test/logs/apache2-error-ssl.log"
        CustomLog "/srv/www/test/logs/apache2-access-ssl.log" combined

        <Directory /srv/www/test/htdocs>
                Options -Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,MultiViews
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(www\.)?domain\.com$" [NC]
                RewriteRule ".*" "https://test.com/test" [L,NE,P]
        </IfModule>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on

        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                SuexecUserGroup test test
                Alias /cgi-bin/ /srv/www/.fcgid/test/
        </IfModule>

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_proxy (proxy and proxy_http) are activated, everything is working, also the redirect/rewrite but it doesn´t keep the URL. Would appreciate any help, if someone got a clue. Nothing is in the apache logs. Did i miss something?

Comment: Do you get a 301 or 302 redirect? Check using the developer console of your browser or via a text based client like wget or curl. If yes, the redirect most probably comes from whatever is served by the server, not from Apache.

Comment: btw, the easiest configuration would most probably be two separate virtual host for the domains, with the intended document roots. Proxying Apache to itself doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: curl shows a 301 redirect
i tried it with 2 seperate vhosts, didn´t made a difference

Comment: Then your problem is not Apache, as it does not contain any redirect configuration. Check out the application you are running on that server. Most applications provide some way to configure a base URL, which often includes the domain.

Comment: there is no application i try it only with the a test index.html and another /test/index.html
apache has a rewrite config, look at the code in the first post

Comment: That rewrite is a proxy, not a redirect. It looks like you are not sharing everything related. Do you maybe have more in .htaccess files?

Comment: there is no .htacces only the apache vHost from the first post and the empty docroot folder with the test index.html and the subfolder /test. I tried it on a production website bevor and it didn´t work, so i made the new vHost and folder for testing on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Try reverse proxy

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod deflate
```

add the following lines in apache config

```
ServerName your-reverse-proxy-domain.com
ProxyPass / http://backend-server-url/
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend-server-url/
```

then restart apache service

Comment: The apache modules are enabled.

i want domain.com redirect to test.com/test

ServerName domain.com
ProxyPass / http://test.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://test.com/

Is this correct? I get errors in browser:
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.

Comment: customize this accordingly and apply it in apache configuration

ServerName your-reverse-proxy-domain.com
ProxyPass / http://backend-server-url/
ProxyPassReverse / http://backend-server-url/

Comment: Check the apache logs and which will share more details about the error.

Comment: There are no errors in the logs, if i set loglevel to debug. Only lines like (initializing worker | authorization result: granted | http: has acquired connection for (*:80) |http: connection established  |  http: connection complete

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable rewrite module in apache.

run the given command to enable rewrite module.

"sudo a2enmod rewrite"

Comment: Yes it´s enabled.

Answer (score -1):

follow this it will defiantly resolve your issue.

install nginx by

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

run it on different port like 8080 with same document root as apache.

the add this lines in apache configuration.

```
    ServerName domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://test.com:8080/test/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://test.com:8080/test/
```

the restart the apache service

Comment: install nginx as reverse proxy just to keep the url is a little bit much, there should be another way.

Comment: you can use other methods to serve the request on other port like pm2 for node js or
php -S localhost:8000  for php code depending upon the /test code inside test.com
and server with reverse proxy of apache at port 80

Comment: Also follow this tutorial https://devpractical.com/host-a-html-page-on-localhost/